# TestNG Not able to fail test from thread

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am using TestNG with Java.

I have a dataprovider method

```
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
    return testCaseDataProvider;
}
```

and a test method

```
@Test(dataProvider = "dataProviderMethod")
public static void executeTestCase (SheetProvider sheetData, boolean parallel) {
    //some code
    if(condition) {
        //spawn threads
    }
    else {
        //do not spawn threads. directly call run method.
    }
}
```

Now inside the `run()` I want to decide if the test has failed or passed. I was trying to do that by using `Assert.fail();` inside run method.
It runs fine for sequential execution, but gives an Exception

```
Exception in thread "T3" java.lang.AssertionError: null
```

in parallel execution.

I understand that the issue is caused because Assertion error was supposed to be caught by test method. Hence in case of sequential execution it runs fine and fails the test, but in case of parallel execution, the test method had already executed by the time we call Assert.fail().

Can anyone tell me how can I fail the test from the run() method?

Comment: You could be clearer about what your question is.  Within a single TestNG thread, you are spawning your own multiple threads and wanting to propagate the results of what is happening within those multiple threads back down into the single TestNG thread to report the result.   Seems simple enough, but easy to confuse yourself between TestNG threads and your own threads.  You don't provide enough info about what you are doing but I suspect your forking threads when you probably don't need to and instead could let your TestNG dataprovider manage your threads.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem your test shows is that exceptions aren't delegated back to the caller when they happen in a parallel thread, you should change your code to pass back any execution exception to the caller, as exception can also occur under normal circumstances when the programmer made a mistake. If the error is passed back to the caller, then your problem is solved.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. But the problem is i dont want to run test in parallel all the time. Also as soon as a thread is created, a new stack is formed and hence we cannot get the exception back to the base class.

Comment: If you use an `Executor` to spawn threads, you have a `Future<?> ` that you can call `get()` on to block until its done, and that throws the exception if something went wrong